# Does bash supports "system" command

Tags: bash, shell

I know c , python and perl languages support "system" system call. I am not sure bash shell supports it or not? Can any one let me know is this supported in bash or not ? If not is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Sudhir

Comment: Why would it? The `system` function is to invoke a shell and execute a command through the shell. If you're running in Bash you already have a shell and can execute commands at will.

Answer (score 1):

Executing the command "ps" in a shell.

C:

```
system( "ps" );
```

Perl:

```
system ps
```

Bash:

```
ps
```

There you are. ;-)